# ggplot2 - order bars by their color

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my barplot right now:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIcJ1.png]

The corresponding code looks as follows:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = ID, y = f0.mean, fill = Entscheidung )) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

I would like to have the bars sorted by their fill attribute (e.g. all red bars should end up on the left and all green bars on the right).

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: See if this helps `ggplot(data, aes(x = ID, y = f0.mean, fill = Entscheidung , order = Entscheidung)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I have already tried this but it does not work. I read that the order command does not work anymore under the current version of ggplot2.

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to reorder the levels of the `ID` factor.

```
# Generate data for the example
set.seed(2345)
data <- data.frame(f0.mean=rnorm(50)*20+300, ID = paste0("ID",1:50),
   Entscheidung = factor(sample(1:3,50, replace=T),labels=c("Chance","Tor","Unentschieden")))  


# Reorder ID grouping bars by Entscheidung
idx <- order(data$Entscheidung, data$ID)
data$ID <- factor(data$ID, levels=data$ID[idx])

ggplot(data, aes(x = ID, y = f0.mean, fill = Entscheidung)) + 
   geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
   scale_fill_manual(values = c("#F8766D", "#619CFF", "#00BA38"))
```

[image]